# ¿Generar un select a partir de un array en asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que tengo un array de tipo string llamado nodos, en el cual guardo 4 strings, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que en la vista index donde tengo un formulario, generar un select y que se llene automaticamente con los valores de este array, llevo horas en esto, no encuentro manera de hacerlo.

```
 //Arreglo donde guardaremos los nodos obtenidos en la lista
            string[] nodos = new string[elementNames.Count];


            foreach (var item in elementNames)  //iterate over the list of elements
            {
                string elementName = item.Value;

                nodos[i] = elementName;

                //Contador para aumentar la posicion del arreglo
                i++;
```

Este codigo se encuentra en un controlador llamado Funciones, en el actionresult index.

Esto es lo que tengo en la vista donde quiero generar ese select, y que los option se generen automáticamente con los valores de ese array.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <form action="Funciones/nodos" method="post">

                <label>Elija el nodo del que desea obtener parametros</label> <br />
           <select>

           <option value=""></option>



            </select><br />

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </form>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

¿Podrian darme una idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: si, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Por pura cosa... Puedes evitar el `foreach` del inicio con: `string[] nodos = elementNames.Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();`

Comment: Ese foreach lo uso de esa manera, ya que estoy utilizando un metodo de un webservice y este me lo exige asi, es por eso que guardo el arreglo de esa manera, lo que quiero hacer , es usar el contenido del arreglo nodos para generar un select en la vista con esos valores.

Comment: Si lo que vas a guardar un array de strings, no importa la forma en la que lo obtengas... al final el tipo de dato de `elementNames` hereda de `IEnumerable`/`ICollection`, por lo que no pierdes nada con volver tu código un poco más legible al quitar el `foreach` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer algo como...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Obtenemos los elementos con los que queremos llenar el select
    ViewBag.Nodos = elementNames.Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
    // Otra lógica y eso...
    return View(); // En caso de que los nodos de arriba no sean tu modelo.
}
```

Y en tu vista:

```
// Index.cshtml del controlador Funciones
<!-- ... Otro contenido ... -->
<div class="container">
    <form action="Funciones/nodos" method="post">
        <label>Elija el nodo del que desea obtener parametros</label><br />
        <select>
            <option value=""></option>
            @if (ViewBag.Nodos != null) {
                foreach (string nodo in ViewBag.Nodos) {
                  <option value="@nodo">@nodo</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- ... Otro contenido ... -->
```

Aquí te dejo un [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e1Mboc) para que lo veas funcionando :)

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias llevaba horas con esto, te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

relacionado a tu pregunta seria necesario revisar los siguientes cambios a nivel de codigo fuente:

en el codigo de tu controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
//Arreglo donde guardaremos los nodos obtenidos en la lista
            string[] nodos = new string[elementNames.Count];


            foreach (var item in elementNames)  //iterate over the list of elements
            {
                string elementName = item.Value;

                nodos[i] = elementName;

                //Contador para aumentar la posicion del arreglo
                i++;
            }

ViewBag.nodo = nodos;

return View();

}
```

y ya en tu view de razor seria de la siguiente manera:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
@using tuSolucion.TuModelo;

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Nodos</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tuNodo" name="tuNodo">
        <option value="">Todos</option>
        @foreach (ObjdeModelo item in ViewBag.nodo)
        {          
          <option value="@item.OtroCampoValor">@item.OtroCampoDesc</option>            
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.